# In Ruby, how to compute the number of days until next Sunday?

Tags: ruby, date

I'd like to find out how many days until next Sunday given some arbitrary date.

If the date supplied **is** Sunday, it should return 7.

I'm using the **Date** Class from the Ruby Standard Library.

```
require 'date'
today = Date.today
```

Comment: The simplest way is: `1 + rand(7)`. But you'll have a 0.1428 chance of getting it right.

Comment: This is a duplicate, only you'll reverse which date gets subtracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
7-today.wday # Days until next Sunday
```

---

More generally, to answer this question for a general day `d` = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 for Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat respectively:

```
DAYS_PER_WEEK = 7
(d-today.wday-1) % DAYS_PER_WEEK + 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't use magic numbers?  If not, I'll just accept this one.

Comment: @franksort, sure: `DAYS_PER_WEEK = 7; DAYS_PER_WEEK - today.wday`.

Comment: @franksort But 7 is the most magic number of all! 7 colors of the rainbow, 7 chakras, 7 whole notes in a musical scale...

Comment: @franksort, how about `(42/6)-today.wday`?  Oh, no, that doesn't work either.  Matt, don't forget swans a-swimming.

Comment: @franksort Answer updated with more general formula with all magic removed (except for the magic math :)

Comment: @Matt I apologize using the phrase magic numbers.  Comes across as pretty pretentious.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @franksort No worries, just having a bit of fun :)